# Separation lines when animating UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

All the cells in my tableView gets a separation line between them when I animate the tableView (see posted gif). I have tried setting the tableview's separator to *None*. The cells are defined in a custom .xib. The animation is simply initiated through *UIView.animateWithDuration* where i move the view the UITableView is sub-view of. I've asket several programmers in the company but to no avail, any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3g48.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of a hack but you can make the separator lines invisible by setting their color to `clear`:

```
tableView.separatorColor = .clear
```